# Javascript text input on input text change format to two decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

Hi I have the below code which sanitises text entered in input text.

```
let formattedText = text
        .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "") // remove chars except number, point.
        .replace(/(\..*)\./g, "$1") // remove multiple points.
        .replace(/^0+(\d)/gm, "$1"); // remove multiple leading zeros.
```

I am stuck at a scenario where i want to restrict to two decimal places without using toFixed(2)

for example user should enter 100.203

Comment: \d+\.\d{0,2} -- 1 or more digits, decimal, 0 - 2 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your second regex to this

```
.replace(/(\.\d{1,2}).*/g, "$1") // remove multiple points.
```

---

```
(\.\d{1,2}).*/
```

- `(\.\d{1,2})` - Match `.` followed by 1 or 2 digits
- `.*` - Match anything except new line zero or more time

---

```js
let formattedText = (text) => text
  .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")
  .replace(/\.{2,}/g,'.')
  .replace(/^0*([^0]\d*\.\d{1,2}).*/g, "$1")
  
  
console.log(formattedText('abcb123.25252.235252abdbch'))
console.log(formattedText('abcb123.2.2gvsgvs'))
console.log(formattedText('abcbcbbc123'))
console.log(formattedText('123.avsvs.123'))
console.log(formattedText('avsvs.1234'))
console.log(formattedText('avsvs1234'))
```

---

```
  .replace(/\.{2,}/g,'.')
```

This replaces consecutive `.` periods if there are any, i.e `abc123.aba.123` here after first replace the string will become `123..123` so to make it a valid number we need to replace `..` with single `.`

---

```
.replace(/^0*([^0]\d*\.\d{1,2}).*/g, "$1")
```

This simply combines the combine yours regex which are used to remove the leading 0's and multiple decimals, this regex means

- `^0*` - Match `0` zero or more time at start of string
- `([^0]\d*\.\d{1,2})` - Match non zero digit, followed by any number of digit followed by `.` followed by one or two digit
- `.*` - Match anything except new line

Comment: Thank you Code Maniac. Can you please add comments on what   .replace(/\.{2,}/g,'.') and   .replace(/^0*([^0]\d*\.\d{1,2}).*/g, "$1")
do?

Comment: @Rigorousimplementation updated with what each of them do, you can see the update

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
.replace(/(\.\d{3})\d+/g, '$1');
```